# Determine replication strategy for Cassandra cluster at run time

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I need to set the consistency level of a query depending on the replication strategy. A replication strategy of `NetworkTopologyStrategy` will mean that the insert will execute at `EACH_QUORUM`. A replication strategy of `SimpleStrategy` will mean that the insert will execute at `LOCAL_QUORUM`.

The `session` seems to have a `getCluster()`. Is there anyway to know the replication strategy for the `Cluster` object or through any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. From cluster, you can [`getMetadata()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.html#getMetadata--), then [`Metadata.getKeyspace(String)`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getKeyspace-java.lang.String-), [`KeyspaceMetadata.getReplication()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/KeyspaceMetadata.html#getReplication--) will get you a map of replication options for a given keyspace.